# Как динамически подогнать размер label под layout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qss

Мой код

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QWidget, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
                startValue=QtGui.QColor("blue"),
                endValue=QtGui.QColor("green"),
                valueChanged=self._on_value_changed,
                duration=400,
            )
        self.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


    def _on_value_changed(self, color):
        foreground = (
            QtGui.QColor("black")
            if self._animation.direction() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            else QtGui.QColor("yellow")
        )
        self._update_stylesheet(color, foreground)

    def _update_stylesheet(self, background, foreground):
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """
        QLabel{
            padding:10;
            margin10;
            background: %s;
            color: %s;
        }
        """
            % (background.name(), foreground.name())
        )
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().leaveEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.parent.click()


class Radio(QRadioButton): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setText('0')
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.setText('test0098908uhjhjk9')

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())


        self.setStyleSheet('QRadioButton{background:red} QRadioButton::indicator{ text:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)}')


        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.label.setStyleSheet('padding:10;margin10;background:green')
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        print('radio-2 h - {}'.format(self.height()))
        print('radio-2 w - {}'.format(self.width()))
        print('label h -{}'.format(self.label.height()))
        print('label w -{}'.format(self.label.width()))

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 34))

        self.toggled.connect(self.on_off)
    def on_off(self):
        if self.isChecked():                                   
            self.label.setText('<div>&#xe3434</div>')
        else:
            self.label.setText('<div>&#xe3456</div>')


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._dictRB = {                                            
            '0': False,
            'rb1': False,
            'rb2': False,
            'rb3': False,
        }

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

        self.rb0 = Radio()                             #QRadioButton() # 'rb0'

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.rb0.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.rb0.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)

        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('rb1')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)               

        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('rb2')
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2) 

        self.rb3 = QRadioButton('rb3')                               
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb3)                         

        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.text()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = False
            self._dictRB['rb3'] = True
            self.rb3.setChecked(True)              
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = True

        print("Button -> `{} - {}`".format(radioButton.text(), radioButton.isChecked()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    #w.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 400))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне нужно чтобы Radio() не было меньше QLabel. И вела себя примерно как если бы QLabel был подключен к Layout находясь внутри QWidget С сохраненым margin, padding, font-size, border,

[image]

Примерно как здесь

[image]

но сделать это динамически чтобы не писать вручную каждый раз setMinimumSize()

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте документацию по компоновке.
Все эти вещи задаются с помощью QWidget::sizePolicy(). Через эту политику можно задать как растягивать и в каких пропорциях каждый из элементов QLayout.

Comment: это не похоже на ответ. Опубликуйте лучше это как комментарий.

Comment: Я уже использовал sizePolicy() но Radio не видет QLabel и как бы я его не циплял. он просто игнарирует геометрию QLabel. И изо этого мне приходится использовать setMinimumSize()